# Objective-C getting User fullpath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

im learning Objective-C with XCode.

Im tying to get the User full path directory, im getting "good" return, but without the user full path (/User/Asinox), just im getting NSPathStore2.

I was trying with NSHomeDirectoryForUser() and with StringByExpandingTildeInPath and the result was the same (NSPathStore2).

Im using XCode 3.2.3 and SDK 4.0.1 on MAC OS X 10.6.4

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void PrintPathInfo(){
 //NSString *path = @"~";
 NSString *directory = NSHomeDirectoryForUser(@"asinox");//[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

 NSArray *pathComponents = [directory pathComponents];

 NSLog(@"My home folder is at %@", *directory);
 NSLog(@"===============================");


 for(NSString *ruta in pathComponents){
  NSLog(@"%@", ruta);
 }
 NSLog(@"==============================="); 

  }


  int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
      NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

      PrintPathInfo();
      [pool release];
      return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"My home folder is at %@", *directory);
```

Should be

```
NSLog(@"My home folder is at %@", directory);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) is a class cluster.

> Because of the nature of class clusters, string objects aren’t actual instances of the NSString or NSMutableString classes but of one of their private subclasses

An `NSPathStore2` is a private `NSString` subclass that is probably dedicated to dealing with paths, presumably so that path-related methods such as `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` or `pathExtension` can be performed with greater speed than if it were a non-optimised alternative.

What is the output that you are getting?